# Print name of current page through included <head> file

Tags: php, html

So I would like to print name of the current page in the title tag of the head.

I include my head in every page like this:

```
include 'includes/head.php';
```

This is my head:

```
<head>
    <?php $page = basename(__FILE__, '.php'); ?>
    <title><?php echo ucfirst($page); ?><title>
</head>
```

I thought this would work, but now it just shows "Head" on every page.

I know I can make it work by just putting the $page variable on every page but I would like to prevent this.

So is there any way to print the name of the current page through the included head.php file without adding anything to every page?

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is how I fixed it:

```
$page = pathinfo($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to create a file `head.php` with the following content

```
<?php

    $xpage = pathinfo( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],PATHINFO_BASENAME );
    $ypage = pathinfo( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],PATHINFO_FILENAME );

    echo "
    <!--

    with extension
    {$xpage}

    without extension
    {$ypage}

    -->";

?>
```

and include in your regular php pages using `include '/path/to/head.php'` you should get the desired result ~ you will see two options - with or without file extension.

To add this to the document title simply echo whichever option is preferrable

```
<title><?php echo $ypage;?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this enclosing the $page variable in php tags:

```
<head>
    <?php $page = basename(__FILE__, '.php'); ?>
    <title><?php echo ucfirst($page); ?><title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like this:

**head.php**

```
<?php

    function head($page) {

        echo "<head>";
        echo "<title>".ucfirst($page)."<title>";
        echo "</head>"

    }
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

    include 'includes/head.php';

    $page = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
    head(page);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems, first one is curly bracket in front of the echo, the second one is that end title tag is missing forward slash and probably last one is that page variable is not inside php tags...

So your code should look like:

```
<?php $page = basename(__FILE__, '.php'); ?>
<title><?php echo ucfirst($page); ?></title>
```